# в чем может быть ошибка? NullPointerException SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public DBHelper dbHelper;
public SQLiteDatabase db;
public ContentValues cv;
public final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
public Cursor c;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    cv = new ContentValues();
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();




    //db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    // this.insert(new News("ggg","wergergeg","wrhgrwhr","wrhgrwhr","wrhgrwhr","wrhgrwhr",111,true));
}


public void insert(News news) {

    cv.put("title", news.getTitle());
    cv.put("description", news.getDescription());
    cv.put("url", news.getUrl());
    cv.put("published", news.getPublished());
    cv.put("updated", news.getUpdated());
    cv.put("author", news.getAuthor());
    cv.put("hours", news.getHours());
    cv.put("descVisible", news.getDescVisible());

    long rowID = db.insert("news", null, cv);

}

public ArrayList<News> read() {
    ArrayList<News> newsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor c;

    c = db.query("news", null, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {

        int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");
        int titleColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("title");
        int descriptionColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("description");
        int urlColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("url");
        int publishedColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("published");
        int updatedColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("updated");
        int authorColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("author");
        int hoursColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("hours");
        int descVisibleColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("descVisible");

        do {
            News news = new News(
                    c.getString(titleColIndex),
                    c.getString(descriptionColIndex),
                    c.getString(urlColIndex),
                    c.getString(publishedColIndex),
                    c.getString(updatedColIndex),
                    c.getString(authorColIndex),
                    1,
                    true
            );
            newsArrayList.add(news);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    } else
        c.close();

    dbHelper.close();
    return newsArrayList;
}

class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        // конструктор суперкласса
        super(context, "myNews", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- onCreate database ---");
        // создаем таблицу с полями
        db.execSQL("create table news ("
                + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + "title text,"
                + "description text,"
                + "url text,"
                + "published text,"
                + "updated text,"
                + "author text,"
                //+ "hours text,"
                //+ "descVisible text,"
                + ");");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {


    }
}
```

Comment: Может стэктрэйс прикрепите?

Comment: много в чем. Если у вас ошибка, вы должны знать и на какой она строке. И мало того, должны сказать это нам, и еще приложить стактрейс, если сами не умеете их читать.

Comment: на момент вызова `read` в переменной `db` ничего не записано. А вы пытаетесь это *ничего* использовать.

Comment: добавлял         this.insert(new News("ggg","wergergeg","wrhgrwhr","wrhgrwhr","wrhgrwhr","wrhgrwhr",111,true));
всё равно вылетает

Comment: это ничего не изменит. Вы должны вызвать `onCreate`, чтобы в переменную `db` записалось значение `db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();` прежде, чем вызывать `read`

Comment: а вы уверены, что БД у Вас создана?